# How to change level of scala-spark's logging to the console of IDE?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have really tried every solution but nothing works! Still get a ton of debug logs so this is impossible to print anything while spark performs calculations.

This is the class which I run and which produces tone of debug logs.

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to set the log level on spark context: `sc.setLogLevel("error")`

Comment: im doint this: `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")`